# Check if values in a groupby exists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using pandas and I have a dataframe called `orders`.  It has 3 columns:  `id`, `user_id` and `order_timestamp`.

The first step I would like to do is to `groupby` `user_id` and return the `min` of `order_timestamp` and return the entire row that corresponds to the min order_timestamp (id, user_id and the min order_timestamp).  This tells me which order id's are "first orders".  We will call this the `first_orders` dataframe.

The next step I would like to do is compare `first_orders` to the orders dataframe, and create a new dataframe that excludes first orders.  We can call that `non_first_orders`

What is the most efficient way to do this?

`orders` looks like this

```
id user_id order_timestamp
1  10       1/1/19
2  10       1/10/19
3  10       2/1/18
4  11       10/2/19
5  11       1/1/19
6  11       3/1/19
7  12       6/9/19
8  12       5/1/18
9  12       3/12/19
```

first orders should look like this
id user_id order_timestamp

```
3  10       2/1/18
5  11       1/1/19
8  12       5/1/19
```

finally, `non_first_orders` should look like this

```
id user_id order_timestamp
1  10       1/1/19
2  10       1/10/19
4  11       10/2/19
6  11       3/1/19
7  12       6/9/19
9  12       3/12/19
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to this question?

Comment: @ScottBoston just updated with some sample data, let me know if that helps

Comment: This is too broad/vague IMO.

Comment: @AMC is there an area i can clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
idx = orders.groupby('user_id')['order_timestamp'].idxmin()
orders.loc[idx]
```

Output:

```
   id  user_id order_timestamp
2   3       10      2018-02-01
4   5       11      2019-01-01
7   8       12      2018-05-01
```

And,

```
non_first_orders = orders[~orders.index.isin(idx)]
non_first_orders
```

Output:

```
   id  user_id order_timestamp
0   1       10      2019-01-01
1   2       10      2019-01-10
3   4       11      2019-10-02
5   6       11      2019-03-01
6   7       12      2019-06-09
8   9       12      2019-03-12
```